# How to use locate with a world-unreadable home directory

Tags: locate

`man locate` says:

```
 The locate database is typically built by user ``nobody'' and the
 locate.updatedb(8) utility skips directories which are not readable for
 user ``nobody'', group ``nobody'', or world.  For example, if your HOME
 directory is not world-readable, none of your files are in the database.
```

Since it's better for security to have a non-world-readable home directory, how do I make my home directory searchable (for me only)?

Obviously, I can just work around it by adding `find ~ -type f > .locate` in `crontab` and then do `grep <search> ~/.locate`, but is there a standard way of doing this using the built-in `locate`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you run updatedb as user owning the home directory, output to a non-default db and then search that db with locate. (or add this db to search path using LOCATE_PATH) ?

Comment: @tonioc: This is the way the script runs by default.

Answer (score 4):

Most distributions will ship with the `locate` tools from findutils in a package along with a script invoked from crontab which will run updatedb as user nobody. You just have to find this script (eg: on Debian 9 it's in `/etc/cron.daily/locate`) and adapt it to remove user handling as well as change the database file. So it the end a basic form could just boil down to:

```
updatedb --output="$HOME/locatedb" --localpaths="$HOME"
```

This should probably be put in a crontab.

And the usage would then be:

```
locate --database="$HOME/locatedb" somefilepattern
```

you'll have to add more options if you are using network mounts and want to index them etc.

If you have root access on your system, and ponder possible security/privacy issues, you can simplify your life and use the alternate [`mlocate`](https://pagure.io/mlocate) tools probably available in most distributions too, which behave exactly as the locate tools, except they index everything as root (thus never failing to index the world unreadable directories) to a database not accessible directly by the user, but use a setuid/setgid locate command that will read it and will  allow to display results to a given user only if this user could access the results in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track. See my own answer, and see if you can contribute to simplifying it.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` on my system (a BSD variant) doesn't seem to have the options A.B suggests. Instead it does:

```
: ${FCODES:=/var/db/locate.database}
: ${SEARCHPATHS:="/"}
```

So I had to do this:

```
export SEARCHPATHS=$HOME
export FCODES=$HOME/locatedb
/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

Then:

```
$ locate -d ~/locatedb <pattern>
```

Is there a way around setting environment variables on my system?

Comment: just create wrapper scripts in your PATH before the actual commands (probably /usr/local/bin) ? both wrappers would source a common file with the config and `exec /usr/... "$@"`